# Why do I get only one element array by $('a') with jQuery instead of all of them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing a script to crawl each thread content of a forum that is not using jQuery. So I add js code to load jQuery (it will show at last).

It does work when I type `$.fn.jquery` in Chrome console and it return `'1.11.1'`. So can I use jQuery handily?

Sure not. I type `$('a')` and it just only return `[<a href="index.php?">foo</a>]`, it has only **ONE** element in array, but this forum does has more and more hyperlinks.

**Updated**: If I type `$('a[href=bar]')`(or some other id) it will return `[<a href="index.php?">bar</a>]`.

I try other way like `$('*').find('a')` it return the same.

BTW, there is only one iframe in the forum.

[image]

Can anyone has idea or meet same issue?

---

Below is js code of loading jQuery.

```
  (function () {

    function loadScript(url, callback) {

        var script = document.createElement("script")
        script.type = "text/javascript";

        if (script.readyState) { //IE
            script.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (script.readyState == "loaded" || script.readyState == "complete") {
                    script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    callback();
                }
            };
        } else { //Others
            script.onload = function () {
                callback();
            };
        }

        script.src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    }

    loadScript("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js", function () {

         //jQuery loaded
         console.log('jquery loaded');

    });

})();
```

Comment: @ArunPJohny still one element in array.

Comment: what is returned by `document.getElementsByTagName('a')`, are there frames involded

Comment: Perhaps that code should be run in the context of that iframe

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed I use jQuery in console Chrome

Comment: @ArunPJohny it return `HTMLCollection[618]`, it seems all tag `a`

Comment: @deostroll I don't know how run in the context of that iframe. But I have updated question there is only one iframe.

Comment: @moreFreeze give forum link here in comments. its working fine on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed sorry guys, it is my company inner forum that can't leak out.

Comment: whether the anchor elements are within the iframe or is in the main document itself

Comment: also try `jQuery(document.getElementsByTagName('a')).length`

Comment: @ArunPJohny it return `618`.

Comment: then try `jQuery(document.getElementsByTagName('a')).closest('body').length`

Comment: So you can do your stuff with `jQuery(document.getElementsByTagName('a'))`

Comment: @ArunPJohny return `1`

Comment: @abforce I try to add some .find() but it will return a lot undefined of array whose length is equal tag `a`'s

Comment: that is bad.. really don't have any clue

Comment: as a last attempt can you try `jQuery(document).find('a').length` or `jQuery('body').find('a').length`

Comment: @ArunPJohny thank for you patient and help. how can I confirm I use the correct jQuery instead of other js function in origin forum?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Both `jQuery('body').find('a').length` and `jQuery(document).find('a').length` return the same `1`. It looks like too bad.

Comment: since you are getting the version number and since the methods like closest are working you are using jQuery

Comment: @MoreFreeze It is almost impossible to guess the problem without looking the forum. May be there is only one anchor tag. So consider providing complete information or create an example on http://jsfiddle.net or Stackoverflow post itself.

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks for your advice. I do some work on jsfiddle.net and update my question back.

Comment: did you have a look at the actual markup? are there any namespaces attached to the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everyone:

I found the problem that the forum has. I debug in the jquery.js and found after

```
push.apply( results,
    newContext.querySelectorAll( newSelector )
```

(it is at line 864, https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js)

`results` just push **one** element in it, and then I found another js from the forum called `common.js` define the `function push`, like this:

```
Array.prototype.push = function(value) {
    this[this.length] = value;
    return this.length;
}
```

So the `function push` does the wrong thing.

This question may be not a good question, because this situation is too special. But I learn how to debug from the js code and **DO NOT** override native function arbitrarily.

Finally, thanks for everyone who helped me.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work

```
var link = $("a").map(function() {
return this.innerHTML;
}).get();

console.log(link.join());
```

Put in function what you want to retrieve from html.

Comment: This still return only one element that retrieve the text in tag `a`.

Comment: @MoreFreeze one reason could be your forum html is breaking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using google chrome here. This seems like an issue where stuff typed in google chrome console window is executing in the context of the parent (or root) page.

Change the context.

See how this is done in jsfiddle.

[image]

Changing the context:

[image]

Now you can do whatever you want:

[image]

Comment: I have given screenshot about frame. It is the only one and others is my chrome plugins.

Comment: Were you talking in the context of a chrome plugin?

Comment: forget about plugin, please have a look the picture in the question which I updated. I'm sure I run the jQuery in the correct frame.