# How to overwrite back origin array.push function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a forum overwrite array.push function like this:

```
Array.prototype.push = function(value) {
    this[this.length] = value;
    return this.length;
}
```

this function(I call it `evil_push`) make jQuery selector work incorrectly(see my another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471240/why-do-i-get-only-one-element-array-by-a-with-jquery-instead-of-all-of-them)). It just push first element into array when the arguments is multiple elements.

I want to know how to disable `evil_push` or overwrite back origin `array.push`? I try write a another normal `push` function in console, but it does invoke `evil_push`.

normal `push` code like this:

```
Array.prototype.push = function (value) {
    for (v in arguments){
        this[this.length] = arguments[v];
    }
    return this.length;
}
```

Comment: You should be able to re-assign `Array.prototype.push` with a corrected version.

Comment: @Thilo I have a correct `push` but I don't know where should I add it. I add it in console, but jQuery still can't select more element.

Comment: Add it at the beginning of your javascript code. And delete the `evil_push` from your code (or even better, don't change the Array prototype in the first place if you don't need to).